# How to sum specific hierarchical columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3], [7,8,9,10,11,12,7,8,9], [13,14,15,16,17,18,4,5,6]], index=pd.date_range('2004-01-01', '2004-01-03'))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['x', 'y', 'z'], list('abc')])

df
                 x           y          z      
             a   b   c   a   b   c  a  b  c
2004-01-01   1   2   3   4   5   6  1  2  3
2004-01-02   7   8   9  10  11  12  7  8  9
2004-01-03  13  14  15  16  17  18  4  5  6
```

I want to sum groups of columns at the first level (level=0) and get something like this:

```
                (x+z)           y      
             a   b   c   a   b   c
2004-01-01   2   4   6   4   5   6
2004-01-02  14  16  18  10  11  12
2004-01-03  17  19  21  16  17  18
```

What I have tried:

```
mapping = {'x': 'r1', 'y': 'r2', 'z': 'r1'}
df.groupby(mapping, axis=1, level=0).apply(lambda g: g.sum(axis=1, level=1))
```

But I got an error.

Thanks for any advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can `map` the first level to create a new MultiIndex used to group. This collapses the MultiIndex (to tuples) so we set it back.

```
d = {'x': 'r1', 'y': 'r2', 'z': 'r1'}
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(d.get(x, x), y) for x, y in df.columns])

df1 = df.groupby(idx, axis=1).sum()
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df1.columns)

            r1          r2        
             a   b   c   a   b   c
2004-01-01   2   4   6   4   5   6
2004-01-02  14  16  18  10  11  12
2004-01-03  17  19  21  16  17  18
```

Comment: A little improvement in the second line of code: Instead of using direct access to the dict "d[x]", you can use "d.get(x, x)". With that you don't have to specify unmapped columns in the dict.

Answer (score 2):

Summing two levels is simple as long as the lower level keys are the same. You can sum and then concatenate:

```
pd.concat([df['x'] + df['z'], df['y']], keys=['(x+z)', 'y'], axis=1)

           (x+z)           y        
               a   b   c   a   b   c
2004-01-01     2   4   6   4   5   6
2004-01-02    14  16  18  10  11  12
2004-01-03    17  19  21  16  17  18
```

Don't forget to assign the result back to a variable.

---

If you need to sum an arbitrary number of values, slice with `pd.IndexSlice` and use `sum`:

```
cols_to_sum = ['x', 'y']
sums = df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[cols_to_sum]].sum(level=1, axis=1)
sums.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['+'.join(cols_to_sum)], sums.columns])
sums

           x+y        
             a   b   c
2004-01-01   5   7   9
2004-01-02  17  19  21
2004-01-03  29  31  33
```

To concatenate this back, use `concat` as usual,

```
pd.concat([sums, df.drop(cols_to_sum, axis=1, level=0)], axis=1)

           x+y          z      
             a   b   c  a  b  c
2004-01-01   5   7   9  1  2  3
2004-01-02  17  19  21  7  8  9
2004-01-03  29  31  33  4  5  6
```